# What plugins do you use along with Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Suggest some plugins you find useful in your day by day work.

Eclipse CDT repositories:

- [Helios](http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/): `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios`
- [C++ Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/): `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios`

Plugins:

- [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/): `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x`
- [Eclipse Linux Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/): `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update`
- [CMakeBuilder](http://www.cmakebuilder.com/): `http://www.cmakebuilder.com/update`
- [CMake Editor](http://www.cthing.com/CMakeEd.asp): `http://cmakeed.sourceforge.net/updates`
- [Qt Eclipse Integration](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration): [`Installation instructions link`](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/installation-instructions-for-linux-systems)
- [Eclipse CORBA Plugin](http://eclipsecorba.sourceforge.net/): `http://eclipsecorba.sourceforge.net/update`

***Please add one plugin with its eclipse update url for posting.***

Comment: I'm surprised a useful post like this wasn't closed by SO for being "not constructive" or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I am using

- Qt plugin for Eclipse
- CMakeEdit for colorful CMakeLists.txt ;-)
- Subversion (tried subversive, didn't work for me)
- tried the linuxtools plugins (very ambitious project) for valgrind etc., but they are not 
  really working ATM

Answer (score 2):

I use a self-made plugin to do automated builds of CDT projects.

THis plugin is automatically creating a workspace from a description file that contains the project names, disables the indexer and auto-build, sets the wanted build configuration in all projects and then builds the temporary workspace.

Comment: I'd be interested in a plugin like that

Answer (score 2):

I use [viplugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin.htm) to get vim keybindings in Eclipse.

Comment: Broken link, please fix.

Answer (score 1):

[EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) - it's definitely helpful although I still do a fair amount of gitty stuff on the command line (and EGit stays in sync with changes I make on the command line, of course).